# Usar un src como variable no funciona combinándolo con un if else

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando crear una tabla donde las celdas recojan un estado, (concretamente una palabra de un txt) he logrado crearla sin problemas, pero ahora me gustaría agregarle un color de fondo a la celda dependiendo del estado que tenga .

Funciona así:

Una aplicación externa crea un elemento.txt con una sola palabra dentro, la palabra puede ser: Completa, Pendiente o En error

Y el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<html>

<body style="background-color:#D6EAF8;">
    <center><h2><font face="Comic Sans MS,arial">Monitor</font></h2>
    <table border="1" style="background-color:#7FB3D5">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#3498DB;"><h4>item</h4></td>
            <td id="celda"><div id="contenido"><embed type="text/plain" src="\\hostname\c$\Carpeta\item.txt" width=100% height=50 frameborder=0></embed></div></td>

        </tr>

</html>


<script>
     
    var data = document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML;
    document.write(data);
    
    if (data == "Completa") {
      document.getElementById("celda").style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
    }
    else if (data == "Pendiente")
    {
      document.getElementById("celda").style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
    }  
    else if (data == "En error")  
    {
      document.getElementById("celda").style.backgroundColor = '#FF6C60';
    }
;    
</script>
```

(He probado tanto con `<embed>` como con `<object>` para recuperar el texto del txt, ambos funcionan.)

Si defino la variable var data como:

```
var datos = ["Completo"];
```

La declaración funciona bien, parece que hay un problema al usar un src que hace que if no funcione

He añadido debajo un innecesario

```
document.write(data);
```

Solo para ver que la variable se coge bien y muestra la palabra correcta.

¿Alguna idea? He estado con esto durante dos largos días y probablemente sea algo simple en lo que no caigo pero tengo 0 conocimientos de programación para mi desgracia.

----------------------------NUEVO-------------------------------------------

He probado a a realizar lo siguiente con fetch como me han sugerido en varias partes

```
<script>

fetch('\\hostname\c$\Carpeta\item.txt').then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(data => {
  
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  
});

</script>
```

Pero nada de al siguiente error: Access to fetch at '\hostname\c$\Carpeta\item.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

Osea que no me deja por un tema de privacidad supongo.

¿Alguna idea sobre como "cargar" esa palabra del archivo txt en la tabla y poder usarla para que funcione el IF?

Puedo cambiar el formato de salida del archivo a un .json o a cualquier otro formato he incluso cambiarle el contenido generado por ejemplo

```
<div>Completada</div>
```

No se si eso ayudaría en algo.

Disculpadme pero tengo 0 conocimientos de programación estoy muy ensayo error.

Comment: En vez de `document.write(data);` usa `console.log(data);` y revisa la consola del navegador para ver lo que aparece, ¿es solo una palabra? Si el archivo de texto solo tiene una palabra, creo que sería mejor [usar fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: Lo he cambiado, y devuelve un desplegable ['<embed src="\\\\hostname\\c$\\Carpeta\\item.txt" width="100%" height="50" frameborder="0">']
0
: 
"<embed src=\"\\\\hostname\\c$\\Carpeta\\item.txt\\" width=\"100%\" height=\"50\" frameborder=\"0\">"
length
: 
1       La palabra que esta guardada en el txt (fijo que solo es una palabra) si que aparece en la celda y el comando document.write(data); La muestra tambien

Comment: Efectivamente, `document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML` te devuelve el código HTML que carga ese archivo de texto, pero no hay forma de obtener directamente el contenido de etiquetas `embed` ni `object`. La opción con `fetch()` no funciona porque no estás usando un protocolo web válido, sino ruta de acceso a disco o recurso de red, que es bloqueada automáticamente por el navegador. Habría que ver si puedes hacer ese archivo accesible desde un servidor web.